# Steam Game, 19.04, AMD, HDMI Screen goes berserk

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games, steam, 19.04

The problem was F1 2017, downloaded and played through the Steam client on a Ryzen 2500U Vega Mobile 8 Envy. Played on the laptop's main display ok, but as resolution was set as less than the HDMI TV display I got those pixels in the corner and gobbledegook all over the rest of the screen flickering.

That said, there are plenty of problems trying to play it. best/max frame rate in pre game post steam setting that FeralInteractive put in  is 40 rather than the 60 the screen does with the Windows version and 60 fps set in Ubuntu display properties.

I use the default Amdgpu drivers which, as I understand it for 19.04, are the only option. Launching the game complains about bad graphics with unsupported drivers. It's like playing without Direct X .
https://support.feralinteractive.com/docs/en/f12017/1.0.6/linux/faqs/?access=sptpkxywbb&utm_source=game_linux&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=game_linux_f12017_support#i_linux_graphics_drivers

Noting that the F1 2018 and 2019 do not have Linux versions, so I am not expected any developments to fix it.

FFB addressed here, I will start another thread for that if I make any progress. Udev did not work for me.
 though the rules were installed .http://support.feralinteractive.com/en/mac-linux-games/dirt4/faqs/steering_wheels_udev_rules/

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set the HDMI display resolution in Ubuntu to the same as the games setting.